# flask errorhandler wont catch errors if view function returns an invalid response

Tags: python, flask

I want to catch all errors and return an error in json format for my api project.

This is my error handler:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception(e):
    if not isinstance(e, HTTPException):
        print(e)
        return {
            "code": 500,
            "name": "Internal Server Error",
            "description": repr(e),
        }, 500
    else:
        response = e.get_response()
        response.data = json.dumps({
            "code": e.code,
            "name": e.name,
            "description": e.description,
        })
        response.content_type = "application/json"
        return response
```

My errorhandler is catching exceptions if it happens inside the view function:

```
@api.get("/")
def all(user):
    a.b
    return []
```

This successfully catchs the following exception and return a json response:

> name 'a' is not defined

But it is not catching if view function is fine but the return value is not json-friendly:

```
@api.get("/")
def all(user):
    return 1
```

It raises the folloing error and returns an error in html format.

> TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/errorhandling/#unhandled-exceptions):

> In debug mode, a handler for “500 Internal Server Error” will not be used. Instead,
> the interactive debugger will be shown.

Turning off the debug mode makes the handler handle `500 Internal Server Error` also.